# Keycloak admin CLI operations inside a new realm as the superadmin returns "Unauthorized"

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I'd like to automate keycloak (20.0.1) in order to create what I need for a project. The problem is that kcadm.sh returns "Unauthorized" whenever I do some operation (let's say, add a user) inside a newly created realm as the keycloak admin.

The script looks like this:

```bash
./kcadm.sh config credentials \
    --server "http://localhost:8080" \
    --realm master \
    --user USER \
    --password PASSWORD

./kcadm.sh create realms \
    --set "realm=demo-realm" \
    --set "enabled=true"

./kcadm.sh create users \
    --realm "demo-realm" \
    --set "username=someuser" \
    --set "enabled=true" \
    --set "emailVerified=true"
```

and what I get is this:

[image: HTTP 401 on the script I executed]

(the realm is not the error, it is intended)

For what I understood, I need to be connected into the realm, thus executing `config credentials` with the `demo-realm` realm. So I tried to connect with the `admin-cli` and the `realm-management` clients, both with their respective clientId and using the super admin account. None works and I'm stuck unable to automate these simple tasks.

Is there something I've done wrong or something I missed somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
./kcadm.sh create users --realm "demo-realm" --set "username=someuser" --set "enabled=true"
```

do either

```
./kcadm.sh create users --target-realm "demo-realm" --set "username=someuser" --set "enabled=true"
```

or

```
./kcadm.sh create users -r "demo-realm" --set "username=someuser" --set "enabled=true"
```

From the command specific options one can read:

> -r, --target-realm REALM Target realm to issue requests against if not the one authenticated against

Since you have authenticated first against the `master` realm:

```
./kcadm.sh config credentials \
    --server "http://localhost:8080" \
    --realm master \
    --user USER \
    --password PASSWORD
```

and you want to create a resource in a different realm (*i.e.,* `demo-realm`) you need to pass the flag `--target-realm` (or `-r`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I was quite busy with my exams coming up at that time, but I never got to thank you properly. I didn't read the documentation but it is quite confusing as I assumed "-r" was "--realm" and not "--target-realm".